# how to break array to obtain an individual data from it?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have this array which has data in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
)
```

the 1 and 4 are the id of data in the database
now I want the data 1 4 individually so that I can compare it with the id of other datas  in the database when running a query.
I am new can anyone help me??

Comment: `$array_variable[0]` and `$array_variable[1]` are already individual to access right?

Comment: a simple foreach loop solved the problem..i feel so stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it directly like this

```
$data = array(1,4);
echo $data[0];// 1
echo $data[1];// 4
```

or dynamically

```
foreach($data as $id){

echo $id;
}
```

Comment: well this did the job thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = array(1,4,6);

$num1 = $myArray[0];
$num2 = $myArray[1];
$num3 = $myArray[3];

echo $num1; // 1
echo $num2; // 4
echo $num3; // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
list($first,$second) = $array;
```